# Counting Particles

Tags: particles

Is it possible to count how many particles are located inside a cube in a given frame?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a BVHTree from the cube, you can test individual particles

[image: Counting Particles in a Cube]

Here's a node setup using Animation Nodes.  I iterate through the particle locations, and test whether particle locations are within a cube using the BVH "Is Inside Volume" node.  Then I just count the boolean YES results.

I'm sure this could be done in python using similar logic.

[image]

Comment: Works great. Thank you! I wonder how easy it would be to give particles inside the cube a different color.